# is it possible to remap or modify ipython to give me $SHELL when I use the ! escape?

Tags: ipython

I don't want to have /bin/sh run my commands, I don't use it for many reasons, all of them utterly valid.

I would like to have /bin/zsh run my commands in python shells, specifically ipython 10.2

I don't think it's unreasonable to want an interactive shell to look at the users environment before running a subshell.

How can i get ipython to do this for me?

Comment: It should end up calling Python's `os.system`, which in turn apparently calls the C function `system`. Have a look for `shell_hook` in IPython/hooks.py

Comment: Doesn't C's system() rely on the last field from /etc/passwd? Is your default system shell already zsh? (If not sure, try chsh)